# Topological complement

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

i have a probleme to prove this theorem:

Assume that $T ∈ \mathcal L(E, F)$ is injective. The following properties
are equivalent:

(i) $T$ admits a left inverse.

(ii) $R(T ) = T (E)$ is closed and admits a complement in $F$.

help me please

Comment: So, I guess $E,F$ are *topological vectorspaces*, and the left inverse is also continuous. And.. exactly what do you mean by *topological complement*?

Comment: Let $G ⊂ E$ be a closed subspace of a Banach space $E$. A subspace
$L ⊂ E$ is said to be a topological complement or simply a complement of $G$ if
(i) $L$ is closed,
(ii)$ G ∩ L = {0}$ and $G + L = E$.

Comment: Ah, are these *Banach* spaces?

Comment: yes! we work on Banach spaces

Comment: Ok, while writing the answer I realized that it's not needed, it also holds for topological vector spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(i) If $S\circ T=1_E$, then $A:=\ker S \le F$, since $S$ is continuous, $\{0\}$ is closed, $A=S^{-1}(\{0\})$ is closed.

The closedness of $R(T)$ can be proved like this: let $f_n=T(e_n)$ be a sequence in $R(T)$ with limitpoint $f\in F$. We want to show $f\in R(T)$. Then $S(f_n)=S(T(e_n))=e_n$, and $S$ is continuous, so $e_n\to S(f)$ in $E$. But then, $T(e_n)\to f$ (by def. of $f$), and by continuity of $T$, we also have $T(e_n)\to T(S(f))$. By the uniqueness of limit, $f=T(S(f))\in R(T)$.

For the rest, try to conclude that $\ker S\cap R(T)=\{0\}$, and all vectors $f\in F$ can be written as $f=T(S(f))+(f-T(S(f)) \in R(T)+\ker S$.

(ii) If $F=A\oplus R(T)$ for a closed subspace $A$, then consider
$$S(a+x):=T^{-1}(x) \ \text{ for } a\in A,\,x\in R(T).$$

Comment: Well, I used sequences, which is enough for Banach spaces, but in the general case it can be replaced to appropriate topological notions.

Comment: ok, but please i dont understand why $Ker\,S$ is the topological complement for $Im\,T$

Comment: I have added to my answer. They are closed, subspaces, and complements to each other.

Comment: yes,$f\in F$,$T(S(f))\in Im\,T$ and S(f-T(S(f)))= S(f)-STS(f)=S(f)-S(f)=0 .so $f-TS(f)\in Ker\,S$.but if $f \in Im\,T and f\in Ker\,S$ then $S(f)=0$ how to see that f=0 ? please

Comment: $f\in R(T)$ means $f=T(e)$ for some $e\in E$. Then, using $S\circ T=1_E$ we have
$$f=T(e)=T(S(T(e)))=T(S(f))=T(0)=0$$

Comment: Yes, but why is the left inverse S thus defined continuous? That seems to be the less obvious part of the problem. S can be shown to be the composition of the inverse of the invertible "T onto R(T)" (invertible because of the open mapping theorem, which can be applied due to the closedness of R(T)) and the projection of F onto R(T) which can be shown to be continuous (or perhaps: should be known to be continuous). – user58664 5 hours ago